# Change the URL of a web project?

Tags: grails, web, intellij-idea

i'm using IntelliJ Idea for a web project and when I run it, the url is

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/
```

Is there a way to change it? like,

```
http://localhost:8080/OtherName
```

or just

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Grails 3.X, you need to add this to `grails-app/conf/application.yml`:

```
server:
    contextPath: /OtherName
```

In Grails 2.X, add this to `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`:

```
grails.app.context = "/OtherName"
```